# Why the incomplete type can be new from the base class with template technique

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

The following code will fail

```
class InComplte;
void f() {
    new InComplte();
}
class InComplte {

};
```

Because it is newing an incomplete type.
But if template is used, the following code can compile

```
template<typename T>
class CComCoClass {
    public:
    static void create_di(T**p) {
        *p = new T();
    }

};

class Book: public CComCoClass<Book> {
public:
int i = 3;

};
```

The base class `CComCoClass` seems to be newing an incomplete type.
Why the Book can inherit a base class that creates it?

Comment: Member functions of class templates are not instantiated until they are actually used. So it depends in which context `create_di` will be instantiated. If it is instantiated in the context when `T` becomes a complete type, it will work. If you try to instantiate it before that, it will fail like your first example.

Comment: @Evg Thanks! Your comment is quite clear and I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

A member function of a class template is not evaluated when the class template is instantiated. The functions instantiation is delayed until it is called. `create_di` isn't called in the example, so it isn't evaluated.